# Retrieve builder from a scala collection

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

How can I retrieve builder from a scala collection being agnostic about it realization? I've restricted argument type to be descendant of TraversableLike, but it's newBuilder method is protected and I can't call for it from outside.

Comment: if you a code example I will complete my answer with a code snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Builder are retrieved through the usage of the `CanBuildFrom` implicit, which is automatically resolved on the basis of the following parameters:

- The type of elements in the input collection
- The type of the input collection
- A suitable type of the output collection.

For example, if you are performing a map on a List[Int] which returns `_.toString`, the `CanBuildFrom` will look the following :

```
CanBuildFrom[List,Int,List[String]]
```

You should rely on the same mechanism to dynamically retrieve the right builder you need.

Answer (score 3):

A code snippet would help give some context. You mention "argument type"...

Whatever declares this argument, does it have type parameters for `Repr`? Like

```
def mysteryMethod[A, Repr](arg: TraversableLike[A, Repr]): Builder[A, Repr]
```

Assuming that, you could do something like this:

```
import collection.TraversableLike
import collection.mutable.Builder
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

def mysteryMethod[A, Repr](arg: TraversableLike[A, Repr])(implicit 
                 cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, Repr]): Builder[A, Repr] = cbf.apply 

val t: TraversableLike[Int, Vector[Int]] = Vector(1, 2)
val builder = mysteryMethod(t)                  
builder += 3                                    
builder += 4                                 
builder.result                      //> res2: Vector[Int] = Vector(3, 4)
```

Comment: scala.collection.generic.CanBuild is a better type for building things out of nothing, so mysteryMethod becomes `def mysteryMethod[A, B](xs: TraversableLike[A, B])(implicit cb: CanBuild[A, B]): Builder[A, B] = cb()`

Comment: @AndreasFlierl, thanks, that looks cleaner. I'll leave my answer as-is as I don't know what the requester is after.